# why am I getting this "Cannot find module server.js"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemon

[image: package.json]I had a Traversy Media tutorial on how to learn the MERN stack that I was following. I had the first part installed on my desktop and it was working properly. opened it back after two weeks and I am getting '/Users/mohamedsoliman/Desktop/Traversy Media/backend/server.js'
the problem here is that the folder structure should have a "backside folder" so server.js should be at "'/Users/mohamedsoliman/Desktop/Traversy Media/backend/**backside**/server.js'"

Not sure how can I fix this or if that's the only problem I have here ?

[This image shows the directory structure I have for the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSKhx.png)

[This image shows the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dQMN.png)

Comment: please post the content of `package.json` so we can check the nodemon params

Comment: apologies for the belated response, I just edited the post with the package.json included

Answer (score 2):

Your code is currently `nodemon backend/server.js`, but it should be `nodemon backend/backside/server.js`.

Comment: apologies for the belated response. just did that and still getting the same thing

Comment: apologies for the belated response, just did that and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your server.js is your entry point for the app.

In that case, run the app as follows,

```sh
node backend/backside/server.js
```

Comment: Please share your package.json file and also what command you are using to run the server.js file so that we can provide better guidance.

Comment: not sure how to do that, I usually type nodemon when I am at the server.js directory!